# what could be reasons of Missing tracking code diagnostic message

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have classic Google analytic code available in my website and I see the lot of data being recorded. but from two days I see a diagnostic message 'Missing tracking code' and looking on details tab find message "No Valid Tracking code found for property AAAAA default url http://www.aaa.org. Make sure your pages are tagged with a supported version of the tracking code".

Can some one suggest what could be reason of that ? is it required to update universal analytic.

Comment: Can you share your website? Usually it could be because you have no tracking code (removed somehow), or it's in the wrong place, or it's conflicting with other JS, or ..... won't really know until more info provided.